# How can i set the search focus at the start of the page in Mozilla with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I have some code that uses a native mozilla browser and it does a find on the text, however this works from wherever the user last clicked.  I need it to start from the top of the document but the API doesn't have any decent way of doing this so I was thinking it may be possible by executing javascript on the page.  Anyone know how to do this?  Basically I want to set the caret position to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(document.body);
window.getSelection().collapseToStart();
```